# Facebook iOS App Policy: Where is the back to Facebook banner in the sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, policy

In the new facebook app policy i found this paragraph

> > If people come to your app from the Facebook app on iOS, give them an option to go back to the Facebook app by using the Back to Facebook banner provided in our SDK.

Source:https://developers.facebook.com/policy

I could not find any "Back to Facebook banner" in the current SDK? How do i detect if the App is opened by the facebook app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any references to this banner in the SDK, but Facebook has confirmed to me that making sure the iOS system "Back to Facebook" button is displayed after your App was opened from the Facebook iOS App is enough to be compliant with this policy.

[image: iOS System Breadcrumb Button]

This should be handled automatically by the system, unless you are hiding the status bar in your App, in which case the system will not show this button.